# How to create a discord web hook using the api in java

Tags: java, discord, discord-jda

I want to create a webhook in the discord channel using a bot. How to do this in java?

(Sorry, my native language is not English)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [TextChannel#createWebhook](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/entities/TextChannel.html#createWebhook(java.lang.String)). This can be used on any **text chanel** in a guild.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks!

```
TextChannel textChannel = discordBot.getTextChannelById("<channelId>");
    
textChannel.createWebhook("TestName").queue((createdWebhook) -> {
    System.out.println(createdWebhook.getId() + " " + createdWebhook.getToken());
});
```